# Graphs don't show when Rmarkdown posted to blogdown on shiny server

Tags: shiny-server, blogdown

I'm new to blogdown and I want to build my site on shiny server. But problem comes.
I followed the advice from https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/161 to copy the `public/` folder to my shiny server.

```
root@jamesVM:/srv/shiny-server# pwd
/srv/shiny-server
root@jamesVM:/srv/shiny-server# ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 4ÔÂ  29 22:57 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 4ÔÂ  28 00:33 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   38 4ÔÂ  28 15:11 bi -> /home/runrunwei/GitRepo/MySite/public//
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   38 4ÔÂ  28 00:33 index.html -> /opt/shiny-server/samples/welcome.html
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 4ÔÂ  29 22:57 public/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   37 4ÔÂ  28 00:33 sample-apps -> /opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps/
root@jamesVM:/srv/shiny-server#
```

But I found a problem that graphs `ggplot2` and `plot` don't show. But `plotly` is OK. 
The folder `bi/` is symbolic link and `public/` was copied there from `/home/runrunwei/GitRepo/MySite/public/`.  In both way, the graphs show the same way.
At beginning I thought there is something wrong with path. So I set relative urls 
true in `config.toml` as following:

```
baseurl = "/"
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "A Hugo website"
theme = "hugo-lithium"
googleAnalytics = ""
disqusShortname = ""
ignoreFiles = ["\\.Rmd$", "\\.Rmarkdown$", "_files$", "_cache$"]
relativeurls = true
```

My hugo version:

```
> blogdown::hugo_version()
[1] ‘0.30.2’
```

`relativeurls = true` didn't help me. Then I opened the `index.html` (in  `/srv/shiny-server/public/2018/04/27/testrmarkdown/`) file which is rendered by `blogdown::build_site`, with browser from rstudio server's file explorer and found the graphs are there. I compared both paths of the graphs through Inspect of chrome, they are the same.
I don't know how to fix it now.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You’ll need to post your code with the right formatting and explain what the error messages was; the things you’ve tried; and make it easier to reproduce your error - I suspect you’ll get downvoted for a question with too little details

Comment: Ok, I'll reedit it.

Comment: It sounds like a bug of Shiny Server to me. If you are a commercial customer of RStudio, you may file a ticket to https://support.rstudio.com, otherwise you may report to https://community.rstudio.com.